# Using \dotfill in aligned multiline equation

Tags: align

I'm editing some file containing grading scale.
There are some aligned equations which have a tag with dotted leaders.
[image]

Maybe it isn't a good idea to remain the dotted leaders.
But I wonder whether one can obtain this result.

Here is my approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\vare}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
Solution:
\\[1em]\hspace*{4cm}
$\dif \vare^{x+y} = \vare^{x+y} \dif (x+y)$
\dotfill ($+1'$)
\\[1em]\hspace*{5cm}
$= \vare^{x+y} (\dif x + \dif y)$
\dotfill ($+1'$)
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the code is somewhat ugly.

The difficulty is to align the middle equations at the equal sign.
The `align` environment can satisfy this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\vare}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{document}
Solution:
\begin{align*}
  \dif \vare^{x+y} &= \vare^{x+y} \dif (x+y)        \tag{$+1'$}\\
                   &= \vare^{x+y} (\dif x + \dif y) \tag{$+1'$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But I can't produce the dotted leaders.

**Question:** *Whether one can replace the white space between the equation and the right tag with dotted leaders?*

Any comments are welcome.
Thank you very much!

---

**Update**

I try another solution, which is not ugly so much. With loading the `array` package, the following code seems not too ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\vare}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{document}
Solution:\\
\hspace*{\fill}
\(
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}r<{{}}@{}>{${}}p{7cm}<{$}@{}}
    \dif \vare^{x+y} &= \vare^{x+y} \dif (x+y)        \dotfill (+1')\\
                     &= \vare^{x+y} (\dif x + \dif y) \dotfill (+1')\\
  \end{array}
\)
\end{document}
```

As you can see, one still need to modify the width of the last column manually.